# BeagleBone Black, Ubuntu freeze when try to echo to /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots

Tags: ubuntu, beagleboneblack

When i try to echo something to /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
console freeze, and CTRL+C, CTRL+Z has no action.
Ubuntu distributive from:
https://rcn-ee.com/rootfs/2017-04-07/flasher/BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-16.04.2-console-armhf-2017-04-07-2gb.img.xz

```
root@arm:~# uname -r
4.4.59-ti-r96
root@arm:~# sh -c "echo 'BB-UART1' > "sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots"
```

I purge end install bb-cape-overlays

```
apt-get purge bb-cape-overlays
apt-get install bb-cape-overlays
```

with warnings:
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.9.20-armv7-x4

Then i update kernel:

```
cd /opt/scripts/tools
git pull
./update_kernel.sh —lts-4_4 —bone-channel

cd /home
git clone https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays
cd ./bb.org-overlays
./dtc-overlay.sh
./install.sh
```

But it not works. Console freezes when i try to echo. What is the problem?

Comment: Console as in debug UART? Or SSH?

Comment: Console is ssh, via LAN or UART, same results

Comment: SSH is not a console. Only on UART you'd see a PANIC or OOPS immediately.